# Too many values error in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to answer the following question in oracle:

List the names of employees who do not work on any project.

Using the following code:

`select e.ename, count(w.pno)
    from employee e, works_on w
    where e.ssn=w.essn
    group by e.ename
    having count(w.pno) not in
    (select e.ename, count(w.pno) 
    from works_on w, employee e
    where e.ssn=w.essn
    having count(w.pno)<>0);`

but am getting the error 
ERROR at line 6: 
ORA-00913: too many values

Answer (score 1):

This is a great example of why you should use explicit `joins`.  To do it this way, you need an `outer join`:

```
select e.ename
from employee e
    left join works_on w on e.ssn=w.essn
where w.essn is null
```

In general, it's best not to use commas in the `from` clause.

---

Here's how you would do it with `not exists`:

```
select name
from employee e
where not exists (
   select 1  
   from works_on w
   where e.ssn = w.essn
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query throws `ORA-00913: too many values` because the subquery referenced by the `NOT IN` clause should only return a single value but you are returning `e.ename` and `count(w.pno)`. If you remove `e.ename,` then it will execute.

However, it will still not return any results as you are trying to perfom an `INNER JOIN` from the `EMPLOYEE` table which has rows to the `WORKS_ON` table where you are trying to find employees which have no entries in that table and the `INNER JOIN` will not return any rows at all since there is nothing in `WORKS_ON` to join with.

If you change your query to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` then it will work:

```
select e.ename, count(w.pno)
from employee e
     LEFT OUTER JOIN works_on w
     ON e.ssn=w.essn
group by e.ename
having count(w.pno) not in
( select count(w.pno) 
  from works_on w, employee e
  where e.ssn=w.essn
  having count(w.pno)<>0);
```

But it will be inefficient and could be more simply expressed as:

```
SELECT   e.ename,
         count(w.pno)
FROM     employee e
         LEFT OUTER JOIN works_on w
         ON e.ssn=w.essn
GROUP BY e.ename
HAVING   count(w.pno) = 0;
```

(But then you run into the issue that you will be grouping on the employee's name and if two people have the same name then they will be grouped together erroneously.)

It can be expressed more simply, and without the grouping issue, using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT e.ename
FROM   Employees e
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   Works_on w
  WHERE  e.ssn = w.essn
);
```